# Excel VBA: Using 2 variables with Match

Tags: excel, vba

```
ws2.Range("D3").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(variable_i, ws2.Range("A:A"), 0)
```

ws1 = worksheet 1
ws2 = worksheet 2

- On ws1 I have 2 columns of drop down boxes (data validation list)
- the selection from the first column of drop down boxes is assigned to the variable "variable_i"
- the selection from the second column of drop down boxes is assigned to the variable "variable_p"
- It pulls its data from ws2 (the range is all of column a)
- It is looking for the selection from the drop down box with the variable "variable_i"... the code works fine, it returns the number row on D3 without any issues
- I'm looking for it to return the row number that contains both variables in the 2 columns (variable_i and variable_p)
- I've tried the following code:

```
ws2.Range("D3").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(variable_i & variable_p, ws2.Range("A:B"), 0)
```

as I had seen that online, but it doesn't work for me.

The error I get is:
"Run-time error '1004':
Method 'Match' of object 'WorksheetFunction' failed

What would be the best way to have multiple variables be the lookup?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key for you I believe could be to use `EVALUATE()` function. Multiple criteria would mean you most likely need an array which `EVALUATE` will recognize. Also concatenating values and ranges to check for two criteria is definately not the best solution. Imagine cell `A1=1` and `B1=101`. What happens if you concatenate ranges to `1101` and you look for criteria1 `10` and `11` instead of `1` and `101`?

A simple evaluate example:

[image]

```
Debug.Print Evaluate("MATCH(1,(A1:A6=1)*(B1:B6=""B""),0)")
```

[image]

In my example I have one `Long` and one `String` variable, respectively `1` and `B`. Would I use your named variable `variable_i` and `variable_p` I could make a code like:

```
ws2.Range("D3") = Evaluate("MATCH(1,('Sheet1'!A1:A6=" & variable_i & ")*('Sheet1'!B1:B6=""" & variable_p & """),0)")
```

Notice the difference of adding a `Long` or a `String` variable? That's because to evaluate correctly in VBA there needs to be two quotation marks surrounding a `String` variable. A number can do without.

Also notice I specified sheet names in the code, you can change that according to your needs

Comment: Thanks for your help!

I've tried adapting your code to my spreadsheet

`ws2.Range("E1") = Evaluate("MATCH(variable1,(ws2!A:A=" & variable1 & ")*(ws2!B:B=""" & variable2 & """),0)")`

(I've set it to return the row number on E1 as a test, eventually I'd have this be assigned to a new variable)

The problem is, it returns "#NAME?" into E1

Maybe I adapted it wrong?

Comment: This won't work! You can't combine worksheet equation and vba into a single line without quotations. I have specifically illustrated how to separate the two with quotations.

Comment: See your first variable 1

Comment: I'm afraid I still don't quite understand. In my example, both of my variables are strings, so I guess I wouldn't use Long as I'm not looking for a number to match. I'm not following from your code why the variable names have 2 & either side of them and why there is 3 " marks in a row. Sorry for the confusion, appreciate the help!

Comment: Going from what you wrote: `ws2.Range("E1") = Evaluate("MATCH(1,('ws2'!A:A=""" & variable1 & """)*('ws2'!B:B=""" & variable2 & """),0)")`. As explained, you can't use VBA variables in a worksheet function just like that. You need to tell VBA you combining the two with `&` and quotations. There are three quotations cause you both need to tell excel you are pausing the formula string to enter a vba variable AND you need to insert a variable within quotations, like you would normally put a string within quotations in an formula on a worksheet.

Comment: Also, in my answer I explained it isn;t wise to concatenate columns to match results. In my last comment I assumed your worksheet is actually called ws2 in your workbook. If not, you change that name accordingly.

Comment: I think it's beginning to make sense, but I've used the code and replaced variable1 and variable2 with their actual names and it still inserts #REF! into cell E1

Separately... If it's not best to concatenate columns to match results, what would be the better approach? A loop?

Comment: No, you see that we try to match the value `1`, this stands for true, in your range where `('ws2'!A:A=""" & variable1 & """)` times `('ws2'!B:B=""" & variable2 & """)` this will multiply all true and falses against eachother resulting in an array of 1 and 0 values. Our match will find the index of the first 1 in the array. No need to loop. Maybe it will all make sense if you practice this behaviour outside VBA with my first example in the answer. Just step through the formula with evaluate to see what it does.

Comment: So I tested it in a new spreadsheet and simulated your first example with the letters and numbers, then adjusted it bit by bit until it was similar to mine. I got it to work, but when I adapt it to my actual spreadsheet, despite the fact I'm telling it to look at sheet2, it seems to only return the row number of the drop down selection from sheet1. This is my code:

`Set ws1 = Sheets(“sheet1”)
Set ws2 = Sheets(“sheet2”)

With Sheets(“sheet2”)
answer = Evaluate("MATCH(1,(A:A=""" & variable1 & """)*(B:B=""" & variable2 & """),0)")
MsgBox answer
End With`

Comment: I could change the drop down to be any selection and it still points to row 3 which is the row that the drop down is located on, rather than the source of the drop down

Comment: But @Sam, you have now left out the sheet reference in the actual evaluation. You need: `answer = Evaluate("MATCH(1,('Sheet2'!A:A=""" & variable1 & """)*('Sheet2'!B:B=""" & variable2 & """),0)")` otherwise it will use the currently active sheet! Hence why it would only return a 1.

Comment: Ah I thought I could wrap it in a With and that meant it would always look at Sheet2. The trouble is, when I put the sheet name within the evaluation I got Run-time error '13': Type mismatch inside the MsgBox (or if I did a debug.print it returns Error 2023)

Comment: `answer = Evaluate("MATCH(1,('ws2'!A:A=""" & variable1 & """)*('ws2'!B:B=""" & variable2 & """),0)")
MsgBox answer` is the code and I'm using (ws2 is the variable set up for the actual sheet name

Comment: Yes, don't wrap it in an `With`, and `ws2` variable wont work in the evaluate, use the actual sheet name!!!!

Comment: Ah of course, because as you mentioned you can't use VBA variables in this type of function, right? I had applied that logic to the variables of data rather than worksheet data. Is there a way to use the sheet's name as a variable via the quotations?

Comment: Out of my head, pls try: `answer = Evaluate("MATCH(1,('"" & ws2 & ""'!A:A=""" & variable1 & """)*('"" & ws2 & ""'!B:B=""" & variable2 & """),0)")`

Comment: Run-time error 438, object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: Hm, probably because quotations haha, try this: `answer = Evaluate("MATCH(1,('" & ws2.Name & "'!A:A=""" & variable1 & """)*('" & ws2.Name & "'!B:B=""" & variable2 & """),0)")`

Comment: That worked - seems like its all good now - thanks for your help once again!